# can any one help me width flutter?

Tags: windows, flutter, android-studio

[image: this is a stuck program i a command prompt]

that is a visual studio is missing necessary components.

[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.5)
X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop
development with C++" workload, and include these components:
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
- If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
C++ CMake tools for Windows
Windows 10 SDK

Comment: Have you tried doing exactly what this very clear error message is telling you to do?

Comment: What exactly do you want us to do? The error message is clear and simple instructions. Did you follow them?

Comment: That's not a question, you have to install the required components

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 2):

like the error description explains, you are missing the VS 2019 C++ build tools. This is only relevant if you want to build and run your flutter project for windows.

You could follow the description on the flutter page for [additional windows requirements](https://flutter.dev/desktop#additional-windows-requirements).

Download and run the [Visual Studio 2019 Community Installer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads).

In the Installer Window, select "Desktop development with C++", the default parameters should be fine, and install it.

[image: Picture of VS Community Installer Window, with selection of "Desktop development with C++"]

After the installation you should restart your computer. Then you should be able to run flutter doctor without any errors.